# Laravel Get 'belongsTo' relation from 'hasMany' relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, relationship

```
class Post {
    function category() {
        $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
}
class User {
    function posts() {
        $this->hasMany('Post');
    }

    function categories() {
        //???
        $this->posts->category;
    }
}
```

I have code that looks like this, and I'm wondering how I can access "categories" on the user object and have it return a Laravel relation.

None of the existing relation methods "hasManyThrough", etc seem to fit this use case.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can look at it the other way? Starting at the categories and filtering by user:

```
$userCategories = Category::whereHas('posts' function($query){
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
})->get();
```

This will grab all categories where a user has made a post to.

Answer (score 1):

An other solution :

```
//user model
public function getCategoriesAttribute()
{
    return $this->posts->lists('category')->unique();
}
```

To limit queries you can change posts relationship

```
//user model
function posts() {
    $this->hasMany('Post')->with('category');
}
```

source : http://softonsofa.com/laravel-querying-any-level-far-relations-with-simple-trick/